# Nginx showing subdomain's contents as root domain

Tags: nginx, subdomain, gitlab

I am running Gitlab on my server with Nginx, and it is running perfectly at git.mysite.com. However, when I access the root domain, instead of showing the index.html file in /usr/share/nginx/www, it's showing Gitlab at /home/gitlab/gitlab.

How can I fix this?

default (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default)

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name mysite.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

gitlab (/etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab)

```
upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  listen 198.199.70.76:80 default_server;
  server_name git.mysite.com;
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change your subdomain to listen to port 80, instead of the default_server. Try using this line:

```
listen 80;
```

instead of:

```
listen 198.199.70.76:80 default_server;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both config are listening on port 80, and the gitlab one (straight from [Gitlab recipe](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/nginx/README.md), which moved to the main gitlab repo: [`gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/lib/support/nginx/gitlab`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/support/nginx/gitlab)) is made to access the GitLab server from '/': `http://198.199.70.76:80/` does return GitLab.

Only a query which doesn't resolve to `198.199.70.76` would use the first config (`index.html`).
For instance, if executed on the server, a `http://localhost/` would work.